# How to preload fonts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pagespeed

In my **index.html**
I have following code

```
<link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/Raleway-Black.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin>
<link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin>
<link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/Raleway-ExtraBold.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin>
<link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/Raleway-Medium.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin>
<link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin>
<link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/Raleway-SemiBold.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin>
<link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/raleway-v12-latin-regular.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin>
<link rel="preload" href="assets/fonts/raleway-v12-latin-regular.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
```

And I **my css**

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('assets/fonts/raleway-v12-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: local('Raleway'), local('Raleway-Regular'),
         url('assets/fonts/raleway-v12-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('assets/fonts/raleway-v12-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
         url('assets/fonts/raleway-v12-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('assets/fonts/raleway-v12-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('assets/fonts/raleway-v12-latin-regular.svg#Raleway') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'RalewayMedium';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    src: local('Raleway'), local('Raleway-Regular'),
            url('assets/fonts/Raleway-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'RalewayBold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: local('Raleway'), local('Raleway-Regular'),
            url('assets/fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'RalewayExtraBold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 800;
    src: local('Raleway'), local('Raleway-Regular'),
            url('assets/fonts/Raleway-ExtraBold.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'RalewayBlack';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    src: local('Raleway'), local('Raleway-Regular'),
            url('assets/fonts/Raleway-Black.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Now when I test it on Google's Lighthouse

it shows me to preload key request of fonts

Now my **questions** are:

1) How do I preload these fonts?

2) Why do I have to use these many fonts? Can't I get a single font file in which I can get all these (Ralway, RalewayBold, RalewayMedium etc) fonts. How Can I make it?

3) I can only find ttf, where can I find woff2 for same?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to preload anything! You can just use Google fonts and replace **all** of your `link` tags with this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" />
```

If you want to include different font weights, add a colon (`:`) followed by the desired font weights, like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,600,700,900" />
```

You could even load several fonts (in one link) using a pipe (`|`):

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700|Raleway:400,600,700,900" />
```

This is fantastic because if another website that your user visited before coming to your site has used the `Raleway` font, then that font will be cached in their browser, improving up ***your*** load times, its one of the main reasons CDNs and services like this exist.

If you want even more fonts, you can check out Google's seemingly [endless collection](https://fonts.google.com/) of free fonts.

**NOTE:** Given the scope of Google Fonts (and other Google services) I doubt Google will be getting rid of it's font service anytime soon.

**WARNING:** the more fonts you use the longer your site will take to load, **I.E:** 5 fonts take longer to load than 2 fonts.

Good luck.

Comment: This only works if your using Google fonts which the OP didn't say they were doing.

Comment: @zero298 You're correct, the OP didn't request an answer that used Google Fonts but they did specify that they were using [Google Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/) which indicated that using another Google product, that didn't require excessive modification to their code base, wouldn't be much of an issue.

Comment: @zero298 Also, at the time of writing, the OP didn't explicitly state that they couldn't/didn't want to use Google's font service.